# Sum the series $\frac{3}{1⋅2⋅4}+\frac{4}{2⋅3⋅5}+ \frac{5}{3⋅4⋅6}+...\text{(upto n terms)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

$\frac{3}{1⋅2⋅4}+\frac{4}{2⋅3⋅5}+ \frac{5}{3⋅4⋅6}+...\text{(upto n terms)}$

The general term seems to be
$$T_r= \frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}.$$

I see no way to telescope this because the factors of the denominator of the general term are not in arithmetic progression.

Do I have to use something else? Or am I missing some easy manipulation?

Comment: Did you try partial fractions expansion?

Comment: Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: @AustinMohr: Yes I am familiar with induction

Comment: Why do you say "the general term *seems to be*"? Do you not know the general term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
T_r
&= \frac{1}{r(r+1)} - \frac{1}{r(r+1)(r+3)} \\
&= \frac{1}{r(r+1)}- \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{(r+3)-(r+1)}{r(r+1)(r+3)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}- \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{r(r+3)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+3}\right) \\
&= \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)+ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac{1}{r+2}\right)+ \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{r+2}-\frac{1}{r+3}\right)
\end{align*}
You can now see telescope and quicky add the terms.

Comment: I was stuck after the second  step. Nice solution.

Answer (score 7):

We have that

$$a_r=\frac{r + 2}{r (r + 1) (r + 3)} = \frac2{3 r}-\frac1{2 (r + 1)} - \frac1{6 (r + 3)}=$$$$= \frac1{2r}-\frac1{2 (r + 1)}+ \frac1{6r} - \frac1{6 (r + 3)}=$$

$$= \frac12\left(\frac1{r}-\frac1{r + 1}\right)+ \frac16\left(\frac1{r} - \frac1{r + 3}\right)$$

and therefore

$$\sum_1^n a_r=\frac12 \sum_1^n \left(\frac1{r}-\frac1{r + 1}\right)+\frac16\sum_1^n\left(\frac1{r} - \frac1{r + 3}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)+\frac16\left(1+\frac12+\frac13-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}-\frac1{n+3}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{29}{36}-\frac2{3(n+1)}-\frac1{6(n+2)}-\frac1{6(n+3)}=$$

$$=\frac{29 n^3+138 n^2+157 n}{36(n+1)(n+2(n+3)}$$

See also the related [Sum the series $\frac{n}{1⋅2⋅3}+\frac{n-1}{2⋅3⋅4}+ \frac{n-2}{3⋅4⋅5}+...\text{(upto n terms)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903555/505767).

Answer (score 4):

There still is the brutal way:

$$ \frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}\stackrel{\text{PFD}}{=}\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{r+3} \tag{1}$$
leads to:
$$ \frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)} = \frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1} x^{r-1}\left(4-3x-x^3\right)\,dx \tag{2}$$
then by summing both sides over $r\geq 1$:
$$ \sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4-3x-x^3}{1-x}\,dx=\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\left(4+x+x^2\right)\,dx \tag{3} $$
and simplifying:
$$ \sum_{r\geq 1}\frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}=\frac{1}{6}\left(4+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{29}{36}}.\tag{4}$$
The partial sums are more directly computed via $(1)$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}&=&\frac{2}{3}H_n-\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{n+1}-1\right)-\frac{1}{6}\left(H_{n+3}-\frac{11}{6}\right)\\&=&\frac{157 n+138 n^2+29 n^3}{36 (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}.\tag{5} \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)} = \frac2{3r}-\frac 1{2(r+1)} - \frac1{6(r+3)}$$

Comment: I just wonder how does that help in summing?

Comment: @greedoid, same. I just see three H.P's.

Comment: @greedoid It reduces to that of finding the sum for $1/p(x)$ where $p(x) = x+c$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$, which is more elementary.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Go on.............

Comment: @greedoid Hum? Do you expect some closed form in terms of elementary expressions? The partial sums obviously don't have that, but you can express them in terms of harmonic numbers, if that counts.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, See Deepsea's solution.

Comment: My previous comment was with respect to partial sums fo $1/p(x)$. In this particular case, the leading coefficients of the partial fraction decomposition add up to $0$ $(2/3 -1/2 -1/6 = 0)$ which is why harmonic numbers vanish from the end expression.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\frac {r+2}{r(r+1)(r+3)}=\frac Ar+\frac B{r+1}+\frac C{r+3}$$ wherere $A,B,C$ are arbitrary constants

$$\implies r+2=A(r+1)(r+3)+Br(r+3)+Cr(r+1)$$

We can put $r=0,-1,-3$

or we can compare the coefficients of the different powers of $r$

to determine $A,B,C$

Comment: So here $A=2/3,B=-1/2$ and $C=-1/6$?

Comment: @Argha, yes. Now put $r=1,2,\cdots, n-1, n$

Answer (score 0):

I copy this from my answer to a duplicate problem:

Formula 203 on page 38 of Jolley, Summation of Series, says $${3\over1\cdot2\cdot4}+{4\over2\cdot3\cdot5}+{5\over3\cdot4\cdot6}+\cdots n{\rm\ terms}={29\over36}-{1\over n+3}-{3\over2(n+2)(n+3)}-{4\over3(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$ from which it is evident that the infinite series converges to $29/36$. Presumably, one can prove the formula by induction, though it may be tedious. Jolley's reference is Hall & Knight, Higher Algebra, London, Macmillan 1899, page 317.

On page 316, Hall & Knight give a general formula for $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over(a+kb)(a+(k+1)b)\cdots(a+(k+r-1)b)}$$ namely, $$S_n=C-{1\over(r-1)b}\cdot{1\over(a+(n+1)b)\cdots(a+(n+r-1)b)}$$ "where $C$ is a quantity independent of $n$, which may be found by ascribing to $n$ some particular value." This doesn't apply directly to the sum we want, but they go $$u_n={n+2\over n(n+1)(n+3)}={(n+2)^2\over n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}={n(n+1)+3n+4\over n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$ and then $$u_n={1\over(n+2)(n+3)}+{3\over(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+{4\over n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$ and now the previous formula applies, giving $$S_n=C-{1\over n+3}-{3\over2(n+2)(n+3)}-{4\over3(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$ Now put $n=1$ to get $C=29/36$ and we're done.

Comment: very nice ... +1